# Why Long (Wrapper) is not unboxed into primitive long while casting to byte?

Tags: java, casting

Why Long (Wrapper) is not unboxed into primitive long and then cast to primitive byte?

```
Long lo = 4L;

byte b = (byte) lo;     // c.ERR !!!

Byte bW = (byte) lo;    // c.ERR !!!
```

Comment: Unless you get a Java language designer to chime in, we can only speculate. But I will say, there's always a cost in making things like this "easier": it increases the complexity of the language. And however much you automate, there's always another "why not do ____". So you have to draw the line somewhere, and this is where they drew it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the Java Language Specification says so!

[JLS § 5.5 Casting Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5)

> Casting contexts allow the use of one of:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a narrowing primitive conversion (§5.1.3)
> - a widening and narrowing primitive conversion (§5.1.4)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5) optionally followed by either an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) or an unchecked conversion
>     (§5.1.9)
> - a narrowing reference conversion (§5.1.6) optionally followed by either an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) or an unchecked conversion
>     (§5.1.9)
> - a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
> - an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2).
> - Value set conversion (§5.1.13) is applied after the type conversion.

The list above does not contain the conversion you are trying to do here, which is an unboxing conversion (`Long` to `long`) followed by a narrowing conversion (`long` to `byte`). Interestingly, if you narrow and then unbox, it is allowed!

The table later in the section also shows this:

[image]

The last row is `-`, no casting conversions allowed.

Comment: What would a narrow and then unbox entail? It sounds like `byte b = (Byte)lo;` but you cannot 'narrow' an object by casting.

Comment: @matt Not in this situation. You can cast an `Object` to a `byte` by narrowing and then unboxing, according to the rest of the table.

Comment: So you're saying narrowing by casting to object? `Object lo = 4L;` then `byte b = (byte)low;` gives an error that Long cannot be cast to Byte.

Comment: My question is, what is narrowing in the context of the object wrapper?

Comment: According to §5.1.6, `Object` to any reference type is allowed. Note that this part of the spec is talking about at compile time, not runtime. The code you showed compiles successfully, it's just that it throws a `ClassCastException` at runtime. "Narrowing" here means that `Object` is the "widest" and any other reference type is "narrower" than it. @matt

Comment: Alright, so they're saying that an `Object` or `Number` can get narrowed to a wrapper type and then boxed/unboxed. In my example, it tries to perform the narrowing, but fails because the Object is not the correct wrapper class.

Answer (score 2):

Boxing/Unboxing is a convention between primitive/Wrapper. They are not completely replaceable with each other.

One line from [AutoBoxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) docs can answer this straight away.

> Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the **primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes**. For example, converting an **int to an Integer**, a **double to a Double**, and so on. If the conversion goes the other way, this is called unboxing.

Not everywhere. For ex : `List<Integer>` is possible but  `List<int>` is not. So each feature does have it's scope.